# Service requirement approach in Android

Tags: android, web-services

I need to run a background service in Android mobile which runs 24*7, And on Start & On mobile low battery and Hit a webservice every 1hr. Can you please suggest me any approach. I tried reading few articles but did not get any idea. I know here I need to paste some code after trying something. But I did not get any clue. Please let me know how to approach?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use the method [`startForeground(int id, Notification notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) to prevent the system from killing your `Service` as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle):

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)

Then you would need some kind of scheduled task to run every hour. Something like a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) is ideal for this purpose, using the method [`scheduleAtFixedRate (Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

The task that needs to be done each hour must be implemented as a `Runnable` and submitted to your `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor( 1 );
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate( new MyRunnableTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS );
```

The `Runnable` task should be something like:

```
private class MyRunnableTask implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
     //Do what needs to be done.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to run a background service in Android mobile which runs 24*7

Please don't. For starters, it is not possible.

Users complain loudly and often about services that "run 24*7", because the services are tying up system resources (e.g., RAM) for no value. As a result, between third-party task killers and Force Stop options in Settings, users get rid of such services. When they do, particularly on Android 3.1+, your application **will not run again, ever** until the user manually launches an activity of yours from the launcher.

Android itself will get rid of such services on its own, because too many developers are too sloppy with their service management.

> And on Start & On mobile low battery and Hit a webservice every 1hr.

Based on this list, you do not need "a background service in Android mobile which runs 24*7". You need to do work:

- when the device starts up
- when the device's battery is low
- every hour

You can find out when the device starts up by the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast `Intent`. You can find out when the device's battery is low via the `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` broadcast `Intent`. You can find out when time elapses via `AlarmManager`, where you establish your own alarm schedule (e.g., every hour).

All three of these triggers should call `startService()` on an `IntentService`. The `IntentService` will allow you to "Hit a Webservice" via its built-in background thread. And, the `IntentService` **goes away** when that work is complete, so you are not taking up memory all of the time.

And, if you want to wake up the device out of sleep mode for the every-hour condition, you will probably need to use something like my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), as otherwise the device may fall back asleep while you are trying to "Hit a Webservice".

This way, your service is only running and taking up resources *while it is actively delivering value to the user*. It is not running and taking up resources when it is simply waiting for some other event to occur (e.g., the next 59 minutes).